# Proguard generating wrong string resource id

Tags: java, android, proguard

When creating a build with Proguard it changes the string resource id with another.
For example, I have two buttons (button1, button2) with label "Create", "Update" respectively. After the Proguard build, the button2 contains label "Create" but it suppose to have label "Update"

This happens only for few string resource id.

Comment: is it possible that You have set the same id to both buttons?

Comment: No. I have checked this by running Lint

Comment: Try clean and rebuild the project, Proguard doesn't have an understanding of Android and it doesn't know the purpose of R.java, so it's highly unlikely it by itself would do anything like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to another build script. We are using crashlytics for error reporting. This crashlytics build file messing up the resource id somehow.